# MVC RenderPartial jQuery problem with selector (ID)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, renderpartial

I have this infoflyout.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#flyoutdialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

        $('#opener').click(function () {
            $("#flyoutdialog").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<a class="flyouticon" href="#">
    <img src="<%= Url.Content("~/img/help.png") %>" alt="Flyout" width="16" /></a>

<div id="flyoutdialog" title="<%: Model.Title %>">
    <p>
        <%: Model.Message %></p>
</div>
```

This is supposed to help me with making a form more understandable.

what i want is a questionmark icon behind a formfield. when the user hovers, the dialog with some extra info opens. the jquery of hovering over the thing and opening and closing, i'm sure i can figure out.

I want to call the renderpartial as so:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("infoflyout", new {Title="This is the title", Message="You have to fill in a date, dummy!"}); %>
```

the problem is, how do i give my `<a>` element an ID. now it has a class, but if i have multiple of these renderpartials in my form, all dialogs will open when i hover over 1 `<a>`

So can MVC render an ID which i could use? or could i alter the jQuery code to make this work, or shouldnt i use a renderpartial?

**EDIT: extra question**

The next() doesnt work. this is the JS file now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flyoutdialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

    $('.flyouticon').click(function () { return false });

    $('.flyouticon').hoverIntent({
        over: function () {
            // alert("over");
            alert($(this).attr('class')); //gives me flyouticon
            alert($(this).next(".flyoutdialog").attr('class')); //undefined
            alert($(this).next().html()); //null
            $(this).next(".flyoutdialog").dialog('open'); //no dialog shows.
        },
        timeout: 500,
        out: function () {
            // alert("and out");
            $(this).next(".flyoutdialog").dialog('close');
        }
    });
});
```

the renderpartial:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<a href="#" class="flyouticon">
    <img src="<%= Url.Content("~/img/help.png") %>" alt="Flyout" width="16" /></a>
<div class="flyoutdialog" title="<%: Model.Title %>">
    <p>
        <%: Model.Message %></p>
</div>
```

the HTML

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Postcode">Postcode</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input id="postcode" name="postcode" type="text" value="" />
<a href="#" class="flyouticon">
    <img src="/img/help.png" alt="Flyout" width="16" /></a>
<div class="flyoutdialog" title="This is the title">
    <p>

        You have to fill in a date</p>
</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: next part of the story: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719722/jquery-isvisible-and-isanimated-bug-during-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class, but render find the flyout you want [relatively](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), like this:

First, change it to a class as well:

```
<div class="flyoutdialog" title="<%: Model.Title %>">
```

Then remove *all* script from the control, and use this in an external JS or in the page, but you only need to include it once:

```
$(function () {
  $('.flyouticon').each(function() {
    var dlg = $(this).next(".flyoutdialog");
    $(this).click(function() {
      dlg.dialog('open');
      return false;
    });
  });
  $(".flyoutdialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jzY2c/).

Now it's going from the icon you clicked to the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling `class="flyoutdialog"`, since it's relative you don't need distinct IDs and you can include the script once to work for all instances of the control.

**Note:** We have to iterate in an odd way here because calling `.dialog()` moves the element to the end of the `<body>` element, so we need to keep a reference to it for each respective anchor.

Comment: i was waiting for you to post the sollution here :D

Comment: Nick, i cant get your 'next' to work. it just doesnt select anything. check my updated code.

Comment: @Stefanvds - It's because `.dialog()` moves the element making this a bit trickier, check the updated answer :)

Comment: should have checked the HTML after the jquery kicked in. thanks. this does work :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your problem.

Would this help :
**Html Markup**

```
<div class="someCssClass">
    <a class="flyouticon" href="#">
        <img src="<%= Url.Content("~/img/help.png") %>" alt="Flyout" width="16" />
    </a>

    <div id="flyoutdialog" title="<%: Model.Title %>">
        <p>
            <%: Model.Message %>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#flyoutdialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

        $(".flyouticon").click(function(e){
            $(this).parent().children("#flyoutdialog").dialog('open');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, this would repeat the `#flyoutdialog` for every instance of the control.  Also `.siblings()` is much easier than `.parent().children()` :)

Comment: Cheers Nick, I'll keep the .siblings() in mind! - Every day's a school day!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the href id inside the usercontrol, there is a overload for `Html.RenderPartial` which accepts the `ViewDataDictionary` , which is nothing but ViewData, which you can pass to the infoflyout.ascx and then set the id for the `href` as :

`<a class="flyouticon" href="#" id='<%=ViewData["HrefId"]%>'>`