# jquery is(":visible") and is(":animated") bug during animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here's the thing.

I have multiple icons, which each show a message in a div.

when i hover over the icon, the box shows, when i mouse out, it closes.
when i click, i want that the box will not close automatic, but only after i click the X in the corner of this box.

this all worked good, until I added animation.

the problem is that the `":animated"` selector doesnt seem to work EVER, and `":visible"` seems to work faulty.

when i hover over the icon, the animation starts, when i click on the icon, during the animation, i want that it will not close when i hover out. in stead, when i click it now, it starts the closing animation immediately.

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".flyoutdialog").hide();

    $('.flyouticon').click(function () {
        //alert("click");
    //when i click and this function gets called DURING animation i get:
        alert($(this).next(".flyoutdialog").is(":visible")); //false
        alert($(this).next(".flyoutdialog").is(":animated")); //false
        $(this).next(".flyoutdialog").data("clicked", true);
        showDialog($(this));
        return false;
    });

    $('.flyouticon').hoverIntent({
        over: function () {
            showDialog($(this));
        },
        timeout: 500,
        out: function () {
            hideDialog($(this));
        }
    });

    $(".closedialog").click(function () {
        var dialog = $(this).parent().parent();
        dialog.removeData("clicked");
        hideDialog(dialog.prev(".flyouticon"));
    });

});

function showDialog(button) {
    var dialog = button.next(".flyoutdialog");
    alert(dialog.is(":visible")); //false
    alert(dialog.is(":animated")); //false 
    if (!dialog.is(":visible") && !dialog.is(":animated")) { //tried to not run this code when the dialog is not open nor is it in an animation.
        //close all the other dialogs
        $(".flyoutdialog").each(function () {
//$(".flyoutdialog:visible") DID return RESULTS (1), the one under animation
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                alert($(this).is(":visible")); //true??????? why is this true now?
                alert($(this).is(":animated")); //STILL false! and that during animation....
                if ($(this)[0] === dialog[0]) { //this equal thing is false so the hidedialog gets called
                    //alert("hide");
                } else {
                    dialog.removeData("clicked");
                    hideDialog($(this).prev(".flyouticon"));
                }
            }
        });
        var offset = button.offset();
        dialog.offset({ top: offset.top - 5, left: offset.left + 25 });
        dialog.show("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1500);
    }

}

function hideDialog(button) {
    var dialog = button.next(".flyoutdialog");
    //alert(dialog.data("clicked"));
    if (!dialog.data("clicked")) {
        dialog.hide("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1500);
    }
}
```

is this me or is this a bug in jQuery, or should i do this differently?

html:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        <input id="postcode" name="postcode" value="" type="text">
<a href="#" class="flyouticon">
    <img src="/img/help.png" alt="Flyout" width="16"></a>
<div style="display: none; top: 370px; left: 315.55px;" class="flyoutdialog grayicon" title="Postcode">
    <div class="title">

        <h4>
            Postcode</h4>
        <span class="closedialog ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <p>
        De postcode kan je met een asterix (*) invullen om zo een reeks van postcodes op te zoeken.<br> Bijvoorbeeld: 92** geeft alle postcodes terug tussen 9200 en 9299</p>
</div>

    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Gebruikerscode">Gebruikerscode</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input id="gebruikerscode" name="gebruikerscode" value="" type="text">
<a href="#" class="flyouticon">
    <img src="/img/help.png" alt="Flyout" width="16"></a>

<div style="display: none;" class="flyoutdialog grayicon" title="Gebruikerscode">
    <div class="title">
        <h4>
            Gebruikerscode</h4>
        <span class="closedialog ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <p>
        Dit is de code of 'gebruikersnaam' waarmee de school inlogt. Deze is uniek.</p>

</div>

    </div>
```

**Edit 2:**

if I run this code in function `showDialog`

```
alert(dialog.html());
```

when I click on the button to fire this event, When this dialog is ANIMATING, it alerts `null`

so this is where my problem is. but how do i fix this, and why is this.

Comment: Can you post your markup?  You're checking two different things...the first is checking *that* `.flyoutdialog`, the later is looping through *all* `.flyoutdialog` elements.

Comment: i know, but there are only 2 dialogs, and on click one is animating the show animation.... html added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i fixed it. (if anyone can optimize it feel free to do so)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.flyouticon').each(function () {
        var dlg = $(this).next(".flyoutdialog");
        var close = dlg.find(".closedialog");
        dlg.hide();

        close.click(function () {
            //alert("clicked  " + dlg.data("clicked"));
            dlg.removeData("clicked");
            hideDialog(dlg);
        });

        $(this).click(function () {
            dlg.data("clicked", true);
            showDialog(dlg, $(this));
            return false;
        });
        $(this).hoverIntent({
            over: function () {
                showDialog(dlg, $(this));
            },
            timeout: 500,
            out: function () {
                hideDialog(dlg);
            }
        });

    });

});


function showDialog(dialog, button) {
    //close all the other dialogs
    $(".flyoutdialog:visible").each(function () {

        if ($(this)[0] === dialog[0]) {
            // alert("dont hide");
        } else {
            $(this).removeData("clicked");
            hideDialog($(this));
        }
    });
    if (!dialog.is(":visible")) {
        //position the dialog next to the button
        var offset = button.offset();
        dialog.offset({ top: offset.top - 5, left: offset.left + 25 });
        dialog.show("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1500);
    }
}

function hideDialog(dialog) {
    if (!dialog.data("clicked") && dialog.data("status") != "closing" && dialog.is(":visible")) {
        dialog.data("status", "closing"); //set the status to closing, so it doesnt close again, when it's already closing (but still visible) 
        dialog.hide("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1500);
        dialog.queue(function () {
            //alert(dialog.data("status"));
            dialog.removeData("status");
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    }
}
```

an extra word:

By binding functions seperately per item, I made a 'link' between the icon and the dialog. this link was needed, because using `sibling()` doesnt always work, like when the dialog was in an animation, the sibling returned null. by 'linking' these 2, I no longer have this problem. It works rather nicely now.