# How can I make sure .animate has finished before performing again

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-animate

I have some sliding images that I am having move with .animate. When I click on the arrow to advance again, the slides get all messed up.

Here's a link to what's happening. http://leadgenixhosting.com/~intmed/

This is the js I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){

    $('#mast').hover(
        function(){
            $('#out-right').hide().attr('src','');
            $('#in-right').show().attr('src','http://leadgenixhosting.com/~intmed/wp-content/themes/imi/images/on_03.gif');
            $('#out-left').hide().attr('src','');
            $('#in-left').show().attr('src','http://leadgenixhosting.com/~intmed/wp-content/themes/imi/images/on_07.gif');
        },
        function(){
            $('#in-right').hide().attr('src','');
            $('#out-right').show().attr('src','http://leadgenixhosting.com/~intmed/wp-content/themes/imi/images/off_03.gif');
            $('#in-left').hide().attr('src','');
            $('#out-left').show().attr('src','http://leadgenixhosting.com/~intmed/wp-content/themes/imi/images/off_07.gif');
        }
    );

    /*Picture Setup
    -------------------------------------------------*/

    var gallery_images = [];
    var divs = ['one','two','three','four'];

    $('#image_container img').each(
        function(){
            gallery_images[gallery_images.length] = $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).hide();
        }
    );

    $('#'+divs[0]+'').css('background-image','url('+gallery_images[0]+')');

    var total_images = gallery_images.length;

    //Images

    var current = 0;

    //Divs

    var current_image = 0;
    var previous_image = divs.length - 1;
    var two_prev = divs.length - 2;
    var next = current_image + 1;

    /*Image Switch
    -------------------------------------------------*/

    function imageSwitch(){

        current++;
        current_image++;
        previous_image++;
        next++;
        two_prev++

        if(two_prev >= divs.length){
            two_prev = 0;   
        }

        if(current >= gallery_images.length){
            current = 0;    
        }

        if(previous_image >= divs.length){
            previous_image = 0; 
        }

        if(current_image >= divs.length){
            current_image = 0;
        }

        if(next >= divs.length){
            next = 0;
        }   

        $('#'+divs[current_image]+'').animate({left:'-=1020px'},{queue:false,duration:1000})
        $('#'+divs[current_image]+'').css('background-image','url('+gallery_images[current]+')');

        $('#'+divs[previous_image]+'').animate({left:'-=1020px'},{queue:false,duration:1000});

        $('#'+divs[next]+'').animate({left: '+=1020px', top: '-=10000px'}, 1000);

        $('#'+divs[two_prev]+'').animate({left: '+=1020px', top: '+=10000px'}, 1000);
    }

    function imageBack(){

        current--;
        current_image--;
        previous_image--;
        next--;
        two_prev--;

        if(two_prev < 0){
            two_prev = divs.length - 1; 
        }

        if(current < 0){
            current = divs.length - 1;  
        }

        if(previous_image < 0){
            previous_image = divs.length - 1;   
        }

        if(current_image < 0){
            current_image = divs.length - 1;
        }

        if(next < 0){
            next = divs.length - 1;
        }   

        $('#'+divs[current_image]+'').animate({left:'+=1020px'},{queue:false,duration:1000});
        $('#'+divs[current_image]+'').css('background-image','url('+gallery_images[current]+')');

        $('#'+divs[previous_image]+'').animate({left:'-=1020px'},{queue:false,duration:1000});

        $('#'+divs[next]+'').animate({left: '-=1020px', top: '+=10000px'}, 1000);

        $('#'+divs[two_prev]+'').animate({left:'-=1020px'},{queue:false,duration:1000});
    }

    /*Image Buttons
    ----------------------------------------*/

    $('#in-right').click(
        function(){
            imageSwitch();
        }
    );

    $('#in-left').click(
        function(){
            imageBack();
        }
    );
}
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API: `.stop` http://api.jquery.com/stop/

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Like @ahren mentioned you can use a simple condtitional check `is(":animated")` if you keen read these:

http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

you will find implementation here: [jquery is(":visible") and is(":animated") bug during animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719722/jquery-isvisible-and-isanimated-bug-during-animation)

Comment: +1 better than my answer! Might also be worth mentioning `.is(":animated")`

Comment: @ahren SUp bruv! Thank-you! `:)` Oh sure +1 to you and this good deed shall come back to you :)

Comment: @ahren Thanks to you as well. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').animate({..properties..}, time_interval, function() {
    // When here, you know that animate has finished
});
```

Comment: In this case, a callback would be inappropriate. -1.

Comment: why? you can assign a boolean while animating, and make it false after animation complate. if the boolean is true, you don't animate other things. When the callback is called, you can make other things that should  be done after animation is done.

Comment: The question title is misleading...OP actually wants to abort the current animation and move on to the next one if user clicks again

Comment: too much code for something so trivial. A simple `.stop()` would suffice, or a check for `.is(':animated')` - agreed nbrooks, the title is misleading! (I actually had a callback as my answer first, but deleted it after re-reading the question)

Comment: @nbrooks yes I didn't understand what he wanted :)

Comment: @ahren thanks, I didn't know .stop() and is(':animated') methods :)